# Is there a vectorised way to draw multiple resamplings of 1:N with different probability vectors in R?

Tags: r, vectorization, sampling

I have multiple (say M) probability vectors (of size N to draw from 1:N) in a matrix alpha where each column is a probability vector so that the matrix is of dimension N*M.

For example, if M = 2, N = 4 and:

```
alpha = matrix(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25), nrow = N)
```

For each column of alpha, I want to draw N samples with replacement from 1:N with probabilities corresponding to the values in the column. At the moment, I am doing something like this:

```
sapply(1:M, FUN = function(n){sample(x = N, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = alpha[,n])})
```

This works fine but I would like something even quicker. Hence, I am wondering if there is a vectorised way to do the sampling using the different probability vectors ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because of the marginal sampling and discreteness, I highly doubt there will be a function like that. Probably consider using c++ for the bottleneck issues

Comment: Closevote reasoning. No [MCVE]. Seems also "close-worthy" as a request for a package rec.